# Pass extra parameters to jquery ajax promise callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I need to pass an extra parameter to the `.done` promise callback of a jquery ajax call:

```
$.post("MyUrl", JSON.stringify(data))
        .done(onMyUrlLoaded);
```

The standard callback, would be like this:

```
function onMyUrlLoaded(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { /* function code */ };
```

But I need to pass an extra parameter to my callback, like this:

```
function onMyUrlLoaded(data, textStatus, jqXHR, extraParam) { /* code */ };
```

How can I do it?

NOTE: this question is not a duplicate, because it's specifically about promise callbacks. Besides this question is two years older than the one which is said to duplicate, and gives a much more thorough answer, and an specifica answer regarding promises.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've discovered that it's really easy including a new indirection level, just like this:

```
var extraParam = 'xyz';

$.post("MyUrl", JSON.stringify(data))
        .done(function(a,b,c) { onMyUrlLoaded(a, b, c, extraParam); });
```

In this way, the callback will receive the extraParam, besides the three standard parameters.

Of course, this can also be done if the promise is stored in a variable, for example one returned by a function, like this:

```
function getUrl() {
  // some code ...
  var promise = $.post("MyUrl", JSON.stringify(data));
  return promise;
}
```

This can be invoked and used like this:

```
var promise = getUrl();
var extraParam = 'xyz';
promise.done(function(a,b,c) { onMyUrlLoaded(a, b, c, extraParam); });
```

There is a shorter syntax for doing this, which consist in using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

When you call `bind` in a function, you get a new function. The first parameter passed to bind will become `this` inside the body of the return function. The additional parameters will be **prepended** to the original arguments.

The following code shows how to use bind. For TL;DR look the two last blocks of code

```js
// To show the results in the page
var $log = $('#log');
var log = function(text) {
    $log.append(text+'<br/>');
};

// This returns a promise, and resolves it after the specified
// timeout. This behaves like a jQuery ajax call (but for the
// provided timeout)
var trigger = function(timeout) {
    log('<b>trigger</b> invoked');
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        log('<b>trigger</b> resolving promise');
        deferred.resolve('A','B');
    }, timeout);
    return deferred;
};

// This is the function we want to invoke
// The promise returns a and b - the extra params
// must be supplied in some way
var extraParams = function(extra1, extra2, a, b) {
    log('<b>extraParams</b> extra1:' + extra1);
    log('<b>extraParams</b> extra2:' + extra2);
    log('<b>extraParams</b> a:' + a);
    log('<b>extraParams</b> b:' + b);
};


// Doing it using indirection
trigger(500).then(function(a,b) {
  extraParams('extra1','extra2',a,b);
});

// Doing it using bind()
trigger(1200).then(
  extraParams.bind(this,'extra1','extra2')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question!

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for.
I omitted `b` and `c`:

`var extraParam = "Casablanca";`

     `$.get( "./movies.xml" ).done(function(data) { findMovie(data, extraParam); });`

`function findMovie(data, extraParam) {
var year = $(data).find("MOVIE").has("NAME:contains('" + extraParam + "')").find("YEAR").text();
console.log(extraParam + " is a movie from " + year + ".")
}`