# Jquery Ajax .done() behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am wondering about the behavior of the code below. `Ajax.chan(tid)` is the ajax call found below. The other three functions are not Ajax related. When I don't pass a parameter to `Display.channelLoad`, the code works as expected and these functions run after the ajax is complete. But if I change that to `.done(Display.channelLoad())`, this function runs before the ajax call is complete. This is probably some basic javascript knowledge that I am missing, but I would like to pass a parameter to `Display.channelLoad` and understand what is occurring here.

```
AjaxCall.chan(tid).done(List.articles)
                  .done(Display.channelLoad)
                  .done(Display.unblockUI);
```

AjaxCall.chan()

```
var AjaxCall = {
    chan: function(tid) {
        return getArticles = $.ajax({
            url: "http://ainonline.com/api/channel/" + tid,
            context: document.body,
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery docs on [`.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/):

> The deferred.done() method accepts one or more arguments, all of which
>   can be either a single function or an array of functions. When the
>   Deferred is resolved, the doneCallbacks are called. Callbacks are
>   executed in the order they were added. Since deferred.done() returns
>   the deferred object, other methods of the deferred object can be
>   chained to this one, including additional .done() methods. When the
>   Deferred is resolved, doneCallbacks are executed using the arguments
>   provided to the resolve or resolveWith method call in the order they
>   were added. For more information, see the documentation for Deferred
>   object.

What this means is that in your example the `.done(List.articles)` gets called with the result of `$.ajax()`. So it will get called with [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object so it would look like this:

```
List.articles(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

And the same will happen for the other done calls in order.

Comment: Thanks, is there a good option for passing `var name` to `List.articles` or any of the other functions? Or should I be using a different design approach.

Comment: This is the solution I found to passing another parameter, `promise.done(function(a,b,c) { onMyUrlLoaded(a, b, c, extraParam); });` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985201/pass-extra-parameters-to-jquery-ajax-promise-callback