# Pass an extra argument to a callback function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback

I have a function `callWithMagic` which takes a callback function as a parameter and calls it with one argument.

```
const callWithMagic = callback => {
  const magic = getMagic();
  callback(magic);
};
```

I also have a function `processMagic` which takes two arguments: `magic` and `theAnswer`.

```
const processMagic = (magic, theAnswer) => {
  someOtherMagic();
};
```

I want to pass the function `processMagic` as an argument to `callWithMagic`, but I also want to pass `42` as the second parameter (`theAnswer`) to `processMagic`. How can I do that?

```
callWithMagic(<what should I put here?>);
```

Comment: If you want to see a much thorough answer, see this question and answer, which is two years older: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985201/pass-extra-parameters-to-jquery-ajax-promise-callback

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just create a `function(magic) {}` as a wrapper callback:

```js
callWithMagic(function(magic) {
  return processMagic(magic, 42);
});
```

Or using [ECMAScript 6: arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
callWithMagic(magic => processMagic(magic, 42));
```

Comment: Thanks, thats 'work'! But only the first time that marketEvent it's called. Next calls return undefined for newArg value, but not for other two.

Comment: @Kulin This should work every time. Did you get it to work as you marked this as answer?

Comment: This post is being discussed on Meta - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338481 (see the comments to the question). Also notifying the asker, @Kulin .

Answer (score 4):

You could use an anonymus function

something like

```
session.sub('Hello', function(){marketEvents(your args);});
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer, thank you! Could be also used with argument(s) on function(), e.g. session.sub('Hello', function(orgArg){marketEvents(orgArg, your_args);});

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which calls the `marketEvent` function. No need to complicate things

```
session.sub('Hello', function(args, kwargs) {
    marketEvent(args, kwargs, 'my custom data');
});
```

otherwise you can do this:

```
var mrktEvent = function(customArgs) {
    return function(args, kwargs) { 
        marketEvent(args, kwargs, customArgs) 
    };
}

session.sub('Hello', mrktEvent("customEvent"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass the function `processMagic` as an argument to `callWithMagic`, but I also want to pass `42` as the second parameter `theAnswer` to `processMagic`. How can I do that?

Okay first, your implementation was almost close to the answer. You want to call your function like this `callWithMagic(<what should I put here?>)`. Also I noticed that you use [ECMAScript 6: arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so we'll simplify our code a lot.

So, `callWithMagic(<what should I put here?>);` can use these parameters `callWithMagic(processMagic, 42);` where the first parameter is the `callback` function and the other one the extra parameter you want to add.

To call this function with the extra parameter, we need to modify the `callWithMagic` implementation by defining a new parameter that will be `answer` like this:

```js
const callWithMagic = (callback, answer) => {
  const magic = getMagic()
  callback(magic, answer)
}
```

Now, here you have a working snippet of your implementation:

```js
const spells = ["Accio", "Aguamenti", "Alohomora", "Aparecium", "Avada Kedavra", "Avifors", "Avis", "Bombarda", "Colloportus", "Confringo", "Confundus", "Crucio", "Deletrius", "Densaugeo", "Diffindo", "Dissendium", "Engorgio", "Episkey", "Evanesco", "Expecto Patronum", "Expelliarmus", "Fera Verto", "Ferula", "Fidelius", "Finite Incantatem", "Flagrate", "Flipendo", "Furnunculus", "Geminio", "Homorphus", "Immobulus", "Impedimenta", "Imperio", "Impervius", "Incarcerous", "Incendio", "Legilimens", "Levicorpus", "Liberacorpus", "Locomotor Mortis", "Lumos", "Mobiliarbus", "Mobilicorpus", "Morsmordre", "Muffliato", "Nox", "Obliviate", "Orchideous", "Petrificus Totalus", "Prior Incantato", "Protego", "Reducio", "Reducto", "Relashio", "Rennervate", "Reparo", "Repello", "Repello Muggletum", "Revelio", "Rictusempra", "Riddikulus", "Salvio Hexia", "Scourgify", "Sectumsempra", "Serpensortia", "Silencio", "Sonorus", "Stupefy", "Tarantallegra", "Tergeo", "Waddiwasi", "Wingardium Leviosa"]
const len = spells.length

function random(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}

const getMagic = () => {
  return spells[random(len)]
}

const callWithMagic = (callback, answer) => {
  const magic = getMagic()
  callback(magic, answer)
}

const someOtherMagic = (magic, answer) => {
  console.log({magic, answer})
}

const processMagic = (magic, answer) => {
  someOtherMagic(magic, answer)
}

callWithMagic(processMagic, 42)
```

#### Teo, seems good but it is to long, can we simplify this?

Well, yes. We just need the concept of [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). The idea is to create a wrapper callback like `function() {}`. This will be the parameter for `callWithMagic`. Now let's modify `callWithMagic` to receive the wrapper callback:

```js
const callWithMagic = function(f) {
  f()
}
```

or using arrow functions:

```js
const callWithMagic = f => f()
```

Let's see how it works:

```js
const spells = ["Accio", "Aguamenti", "Alohomora", "Aparecium", "Avada Kedavra", "Avifors", "Avis", "Bombarda", "Colloportus", "Confringo", "Confundus", "Crucio", "Deletrius", "Densaugeo", "Diffindo", "Dissendium", "Engorgio", "Episkey", "Evanesco", "Expecto Patronum", "Expelliarmus", "Fera Verto", "Ferula", "Fidelius", "Finite Incantatem", "Flagrate", "Flipendo", "Furnunculus", "Geminio", "Homorphus", "Immobulus", "Impedimenta", "Imperio", "Impervius", "Incarcerous", "Incendio", "Legilimens", "Levicorpus", "Liberacorpus", "Locomotor Mortis", "Lumos", "Mobiliarbus", "Mobilicorpus", "Morsmordre", "Muffliato", "Nox", "Obliviate", "Orchideous", "Petrificus Totalus", "Prior Incantato", "Protego", "Reducio", "Reducto", "Relashio", "Rennervate", "Reparo", "Repello", "Repello Muggletum", "Revelio", "Rictusempra", "Riddikulus", "Salvio Hexia", "Scourgify", "Sectumsempra", "Serpensortia", "Silencio", "Sonorus", "Stupefy", "Tarantallegra", "Tergeo", "Waddiwasi", "Wingardium Leviosa"]
const len = spells.length

const random = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * max)

const callWithMagic = callback => callback()

const getMagic = () => spells[random(len)]

const someOtherMagic = (magic, answer) => console.log({magic, answer})

const processMagic = (magic, answer) => someOtherMagic(magic, answer)

callWithMagic(function() {
  const magic = getMagic()
  return processMagic(magic, 42)
})
```

Now let's simplify `callWithMagic` as `const callWithMagic = f => f()`.

```js
const magic = getMagic()
callWithMagic(magic => processMagic(magic, 42))
```

```js
const spells = ["Accio", "Aguamenti", "Alohomora", "Aparecium", "Avada Kedavra", "Avifors", "Avis", "Bombarda", "Colloportus", "Confringo", "Confundus", "Crucio", "Deletrius", "Densaugeo", "Diffindo", "Dissendium", "Engorgio", "Episkey", "Evanesco", "Expecto Patronum", "Expelliarmus", "Fera Verto", "Ferula", "Fidelius", "Finite Incantatem", "Flagrate", "Flipendo", "Furnunculus", "Geminio", "Homorphus", "Immobulus", "Impedimenta", "Imperio", "Impervius", "Incarcerous", "Incendio", "Legilimens", "Levicorpus", "Liberacorpus", "Locomotor Mortis", "Lumos", "Mobiliarbus", "Mobilicorpus", "Morsmordre", "Muffliato", "Nox", "Obliviate", "Orchideous", "Petrificus Totalus", "Prior Incantato", "Protego", "Reducio", "Reducto", "Relashio", "Rennervate", "Reparo", "Repello", "Repello Muggletum", "Revelio", "Rictusempra", "Riddikulus", "Salvio Hexia", "Scourgify", "Sectumsempra", "Serpensortia", "Silencio", "Sonorus", "Stupefy", "Tarantallegra", "Tergeo", "Waddiwasi", "Wingardium Leviosa"]
const len = spells.length

const random = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * max)

const callWithMagic = f => f()

const getMagic = () => spells[random(len)]

const someOtherMagic = (magic, answer) => console.log({magic, answer})

const processMagic = (magic, answer) => someOtherMagic(magic, answer)

callWithMagic(() => {
  const magic = getMagic()
  processMagic(magic, 42)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind argument object to callback function:

```
var varObject = {var1: "findButton", var2: true};

function cbFunc() {
    console.log(this.var1+ ":" + this.var2);
}

//Example callback
datatable.ajax.reload(cbFunc.bind(varObject));
```