# Mixing in variables in a promise chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

So I have a a promise chain that solves a certain callback hell I was experiencing.

Here's what the chain looks like:

```
server.exchange(oauth2orize.exchange.password(
    function(client, email, password, scope, done) {
        users.findOne({email: email})
            .then(authenticateUser) // mix in password here?
            .then(deleteExistingTokens) 
            .then(createAndSaveNewTokens) 
            .then(function(results){
                done(null, results[0], results[1], {'expires_in': tokenLife});
            }).catch(err => {done(err);});
    }));
```

So **users.findOne** returns a promise that returns my user. I need to 'mix in' the password to authenticate against. Given that this is my definition of authenticateUser, how would I go about inserting new variables in the chain?

```
const authenticateUser = (err, user) => { // add password here?
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!user) {
            reject('User not found');
        } 
        try {
            return User(user).authenticate(password)
            .then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    resolve(user);
                } else {
                    reject('Invalid password');
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            reject('Invalid user');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: That definition of `authenticateUser` isn't compatible with your using it with `then`, or with passing `password` into it. It will need to be updated.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Comment: It's worth checking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/4543207) first.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of [Pass an extra argument to a callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40802071/3853934)

Comment: Yes you're right. I was unable to find the right terminology for the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do that by using an inline function:

```
.then(value => authenticateUser(value, password)) // mix in password here?
```

You'll have to update `authenticateUser`, though, since the signature in your question is an old-style NodeJS callback which doesn't accept a password, not a function meant to be passed into `then`.

Perhaps something like this (see comments, but also keep reading):

```
const authenticateUser = (user, password) => {
    // We shouldn't need to create a new promise here, we have one
    // from `authenticate` below we can use
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!user) {                       // This shouldn't be
            reject('User not found');      // necessary...?
        }                                  // ...
        try {
            // No `return` on th enext line, doesn't do anything
            // useful in the Ppromise init callback
            User(user).authenticate(password)
            .then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    resolve(user);
                } else {
                    reject('Invalid password');
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            reject('Invalid user');
        }
    });
};
```

Note that in the above, I've left the logic in the `then` callback on `authenticate` alone, but it shouldn't be *resolving* with `null` for the user, so your `then` callback should be able to assume the user is valid (which simplifies the above). `authenticate` should *reject* if the authentication fails.

Also note that since `authenticate` returns a promise, we shouldn't have to create a new one in `authenticateUser`.

Here's my take at a completely new `authenticateUser`:

```
const authenticateUser = (user, password) => {
    // This `try` is only here to guard against possible exceptions
    // from `User` or  `authenticate`
    try {
        return User(user).authenticate(password);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: I noticed you only have value there. Doesn't the function signature put error in first?

Comment: @MathieuBertin: No. That's old-style NodeJS callbacks. When using Promises, success and failure take different paths. Resolution is success and it follows the `then` trail (the first function passed to `then`). Rejection is error and it follows the `catch` trail (or the second function passed to `then`).