# How to call functions dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function where I would like to call `classList` methods dynamically, something like this:

```
function expand(action) {
  searchContainer.classList[action]("expanded");
}
button.addEventListener("click", expand('add'), false);
searchContainer.addEventListener("onblur", expand('remove'), false);
```

But not sure how can I do that?

Comment: Bind or use an anonymous function

Comment: @Bergi Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40802071/5647260

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks for the link, I didn't remember that one

Comment: @AndrewLi I have managed to do it the way it is suggested in the link you posted, but not sure how can I do this with binding, would you be so kind and post an example for this case? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Leff Have you tried `function() { expand('add') }`?

Comment: Yes, but obviously wrongly since I still get an error ```classList.action is not a function```, so still not sure how to implement this