# Simple Nested Callback in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, nested

This is the most basic ***Nested Callback*** I could think of, and it is giving me an error[posted below]

```js
function a (callback) {
    console.log('first print a')
    callback()
}

function b (callback) {
    console.log('b after a')
    callback()
}

function c () {
    console.log('c after b')
}

a(b(c))
```

**Output/Error -**

b after a
c after b
first print a
/nodejs/file.js:33
    callback()
    ^
TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: `b` isn't returning anything, which means `a` is being called with `undefined`. `a(undefined)` -> inside `a`, it tries to call `callback`, but `callback` is not a function - it's undefined.

Comment: but so isn't 'c', how come b's callback isn't returning any error

Comment: Because you're not calling `c`, you're passing `c` as a parameter to `b` without calling it first. `a(b(c()))` *would* generate an error, because `c` doesn't return anything, resolving to `a(b(undefined))`.

Comment: oh, I think I get it now, since I'm passing b(c) to a - it thinks of it as a function that returns something... Am I right?

Comment: Both `a` and `b` are followed by calling parenthesis, making `a(b(c))` evaluate the same as `var result = b(c); a(result);`. – Related: [Pass an extra argument to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802071/pass-an-extra-argument-to-a-callback-function)

Comment: Please avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: thank you very much, I get it now.. I'm new to Node.js and this had me going nuts

Comment: `a(function() {    
  b(function() {    
    c()    
  })    
})`    
can anyone explain how this works for the same.

Answer (score -1):

You may use like this:

```js
function a (callback) {
    console.log('first print a')
    return callback
}

function b (callback) {
    console.log('b after a')
    return callback
}

function c () {
    console.log('c after b')
}

a(b(c()))
```