# naming a function and adding event listeners to it causes "not defined"

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm still new to JavaScript and i'm having the below issue.

I'd like to name/declare my function and then use its name as listener to add/remove click events easily. the main reason for this is so I can **remove** the click events whenever some condition happens.

Brief of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
function game() {
// 
}
```

The problem i'm having is when I add the event like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    card = cards[i];
    card.addEventListener('click',  game);
}
```

I get an error with the **named function** game that says:

> i is not defined

However, this error doesn't happen when I put the function as anonymous inside the listener parameter.

```
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    card = cards[i];
    card.addEventListener('click', function game() {
      //
}
```

Declaring `i` globally didn't work nor passing `i` as parameter.

- Full code with **anonymous function**: [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVmvoz)
- Full code with **named function** (what I want to work): [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Abdulelah/t67dzk84/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass an extra argument to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802071/pass-an-extra-argument-to-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access different `i`s, you need different closures, and therefore you got different function references. You could store them directly in the card to be able to remove them later on:

```
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  const card = cards[i];
  card.addEventListener('click', card._click = function game() {
    //
  });
}
```

Then you can remove it later with:

```
card.removeEventListener("click", card._click);
```

---

The same also works if you move `game` outside and add a curried parameter for `i` (might be cleaner):

```
const game = i => () => {
  // ...
 };

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  const card = cards[i];
  card.addEventListener('click', card._click = game(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! One question if you don't mind, why can't I rename "card._click" to something like "cardListener" for example?

Comment: @abdulelah you can :) just make sure that the property doesnt exist on card already...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your `game` function doesn't know about `i` because `i` doesn't exist within your `game` function due to variable scoping. In order to fix this you can pass `i` as a argument into `game` like so:

```
card.addEventListener('click', _ => game(i));
```

In the above line, your calling an arrow function, which then calls the `game` function. This allows you to pass an argument into `game`.

And then in your `game` method accept the variable `i` as an argument:

```
function game(i) {
```

See working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/clapynick/43ab2ngv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `lexical scoping` in javascript to understand why `i` is not available inside the named function `game`

Inside game function, it can only refer variables that are within in lexical scope (or inside `this` which is a topic of its own)

Simply put, you can pass the 'i' to the game to get it working. But since the addEventListener expects a function, you should create a function factory that employs a bit of `closure`

edit your game as

```
let game = (i) => () => {
  //existing game function 
}
```

now use `card.addEventListener('click',  game(i));` and it should work as expected

Here is a working fiddle for your reference : https://jsfiddle.net/uch1arny/2/