# pass arguments to callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to pass additional parameters to the callback function

```
function x(logic){
return logic();
}
x(sum, 5, 2);
function sum(){
console.log('sum is ', a + b);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an extra argument to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802071/pass-an-extra-argument-to-a-callback-function)

Comment: Or use rest parameters `function x(logic, ...rest) { return logic(...rest); }` You'll need to add `a` and `b` to your `sum` function though...

Comment: @Ivar not exactly

Answer (score 0):

My problem has resolved with .apply() method

```
function x(logic, params){
return logic.apply(null, params);
}

let sum = (a, b) => console.log('sum is', a + b);
let sub = (a, b) => console.log('sub is', a - b)
let multi = (a, b) => console.log('multy is', a * b)
let div = (a, b) => console.log('div is', a / b)

x(sum, [7, 5]);
x(sub, [7, 5]);
x(multi, [7, 5]);
x(div, [7, 5]);
```

Comment: You changed the signature of your `x` method, so this doesn't actually answer your own question.