# Socket.io callback function scope

Tags: javascript, socket.io, scope

In socket.io, the basic server-side connection code typically looks somewhat like this:

```js
// When a client connects to this server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    // When a player is ready to start the game
    socket.on('playerReady', (playerData) => {        
        console.log(`playerReady received from client ${socket.id} with data ${playerData}`);
    });
});
```

My question is about the scope of the `socket` variable.

For better code structure, is it possible to do something like the following, and have access to both `socket` and `playerData` within the callback function?

```js
// When a client connects to this server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    // When a player is ready to start the game
    socket.on('playerReady', onPlayerReady);
});

// Callback function
onPlayerReady = (playerData) => {

    // Problem: socket is not defined
    console.log(`playerReady received from client ${socket.id} with data ${playerData}`);
};
```

NB: Caching `socket` as a global variable does not appear to be suitable, since it appears that it has a different value for different clients.

Comment: `const onPlayerReady = socket => playerData => { ... }` and `socket.on('playerReady', onPlayerReady(socket));`

Comment: Without currying you can do `socket.on('playerReady', pd => onPlayerReady(socket, pd));` and `function onPlayerReady(socket, playerData) { ... }`

Comment: (note that obviously none of this is in any way specific to socket.io)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you, both of these options work! I think I'll go with the first one, as it reduces the number of times I have to repeat the `pd` argument. If you would like to formulate your comments into an Answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: This question is basically a dupe of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802071/pass-an-extra-argument-to-a-callback-function