# passing another argument into event listener?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit

I have a rudimentary `keydown` listener.

```
private _foo(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   /// 
}

<div @keydown=${this._foo}>test</div>
```

---

If I want to pass a function into that, why can't I just add it as an argument like:

```
<div @keydown=${this._foo(myOtherFunc)}>test</div>
```

instead, I need to do the following as an anonymous function but I don't understand why?

```
private _foo(event: KeyboardEvent, myOtherFunc: Function) {
   
   /// 
}

<div @keydown=${(event: KeyboardEvent) => this._foo(event, myOtherFunc)}>test</div>
```

Comment: `keyDown=${this._foo(...)}` is just invoking `this.foo` and setting its result to the `keyDown` handler. The second one is making a new function that will invoke `this._foo` later when it's invoked. If you wan to use `this.foo(...)` in that manner, it should return an event handling function.

Comment: ah yes, it's invoking it!  thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an extra argument to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802071/pass-an-extra-argument-to-a-callback-function)