# Can you pass arguments into an event listener callback function without using arrow notation?

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments, addeventlistener

I've been looking for a solution to this but I can't find the right resources.
I'm trying to create an event listener for a button to print on the console. I also need this event to be removed after.

I made the callback function a function declaration outside of the event listener arguments, as to me understanding, the same function needs to be referenced in order to remove it from the event. See attempt 3.

By creating a callback function declaration, I need to pass in arguments. If I pass in arguments in the event listener, the event invokes immediately on page load. See attempt 2.

If I simply don't pass in arguments or have `()` at all, I can remove the function from the event but the function will not work as intended since there's no arguments.

This seems like such a simple concept and I've been researching for a solution but cannot understand what I'm missing here.

```
// callback function
function printText(str){
    console.log(str)
}

// attempt 1: no arguments + can remove function after
item.addEventListener('click', printText); 
item.removeEventListener('click', printText);

// attempt 2: // prints but invokes immediately, even when event hasn't happen
item.addEventListener('click', printText('text')); 

// attempt 3:  works but cannot remove after due to being unable to reference the same function
item.addEventListener('click', () => printText('text'));
```

Edit: My goal is to see if there's a way to solve this problem given the circumstances. I have referred to the duplicates to this question but none of them solve my problem or have been addressed in my attempts. I need to pass parameters to my function. I cannot use an anonymous function + the function must be able to be referenced outside of `addeventlistener()`'s arguments so I can remove the function later.

I've commented that this is not the EXACT code that I'm trying to find the solution to, but it is mimicking what I want to achieve. I'm not looking for a step-by-step solution, but mostly trying to figure out if what I'm looking to achieve is even possible. Is there no way to pass parameters into a callback function that can be referenced at a later point to remove from the event listener?

Comment: `printText.bind(null, 'text')` or `function printText(arg) { return function() { console.log(arg) } }`. There must be a good dupe somewhere that I can't seem to find just yet.

Comment: @InSync No, OP is not asking for [how to pass arguments to the `printText`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40802071/1048572), they know how to achieve that with the arrow function. They're asking how to remove such an anonymous function as an event handler. Using `bind` or a `function` closure doesn't solve this.

Comment: "*By creating a callback function declaration, I need to pass in arguments.*" - why? Can't you just declare `function printText() { console.log('text'); }`, why do you think you need to declare a parameter for the callback?

Comment: @Bergi I'm actually not trying to solve this EXACT code, rather this is a simplified example mimicking to what I'm looking to achieve. So no it's not always gonna be `'text'`, but the arguments will be variables that will be calculated prior to the event listener firing and callback function.

Comment: Calculated by what code, where, when? Make `str` a variable in the same scope as `printText`, not a parameter.

Comment: @Bergi I want for there to be multiple buttons but each will print text depending on the button. Example - Button 1, Button 2, Button 3. Clicking Button 1 will print 'button 1' vs Button 2 will print 'button 2'. So even if I made a `str` variable in `printText` I don't know how `printText` will know what to make `str` to be.

Comment: Use closures (like you already did): declare a separate `str` variable and `printText` function for each button, e.g. by putting it in a loop over the buttons/texts or by wrapping it in a function that takes the button and text as parameters.

Comment: Why do you need this? We might be able to better help you if we'd had more context.